# Upvote then downvote bug for users with less than 125 rep

Tags: discussion, bug

If a user with less than 125 reputation up votes a post, they do not have the ability to remove their up vote via down voting, as down voting is disabled for users with less than 125 reputation.

Is this intentional, or is it a bug?

Edit: Shouldn't it be clarified in the user interface that up voting again removes the original up vote? Why is the current process more effective than allowing a down vote for a user < 125 reputation, if the user first up voted?

Comment: Clicking again on the upvote button removes it.

Comment: Current tooltip on the vote arrow for a voted-up question: “This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)”